# how to get the parameter from store procedure with php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

This is my code in php for call to my stored procedure in MySQL:

```
$result2 = mysql_query("call cuotes_sp('$number',@date)");
```

`$number` is the value of the variable to give to SP and `@date` is the variable that returned from the SP.

**Question:** *How get the value of `@date` in php?*

Comment: Like `SELECT @date as result`.

Comment: @corrupt , something like this?    $myvar=result2("select @fecha_vencimiento");  thanks

Comment: Nope, like `$myvar = mysql_result(mysql_query('SELECT @date as result'), 0);`. Also, please note that `mysql` extension is **deprecated**.